# Clang dynamic memory analyzer not referencing back to source code Red Hat 6.3

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

We recently built the 3.3 release of clang/llvm using the Fedora 20 packaging process as a guide to unpacking, moving the different parts to the correct location and building the compiler tool chain. All seems to be working correctly except the dynamic memory analyzer is not referencing back to the source code. The same usage on the Fedora platform does reference back to the source code.

This is our first attempt to use the clang/llvm tool set. Also this is the first question asked in this forum which seems a bit different on its organization from all the others I have participated in so my appologies in advance if I have not figured out the nuances of posting a question here. Does seem odd that the main projects do not seem to have a way of asking questions.

Comment: To add an omission, the GCC compiler version 4.4.6 on Red Hat 6.3 does not have support for C++11 standard so the current build is without C++11 support. Two possible things to be done are; re-configure to use clang to build clang/llvm and add the c++11 support and or update to the latest 3.4 release.

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution, do not know quite why we needed to add the extra
environment setup. Compiling as follows:
PATH=/net/fas4045/home3/jq031c/llvm_sandbox/bin:$PATH make -j 16
DEPFILES= CXX=clang++ CC=clang CXXFLAGS="-fsanitize=memory
-fsanitize-memory-track-origins -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
LDXFLAGS=-fsanitize=memory

Runing as follows:
MSAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=/net/fas4045/home3/jq031c/llvm_sandbox/bin/llvm-symbolizer ./runtests.sh

We can understand that we need to add the analysis option to the link flags as we do a two step build of compile followed by link. The discovery after searching was the need to define the path to llvm-symbolizer with an environment variable which none of the other dynamic analysis options seems to need.